# looking for an identity for higher jet bundle $J^kM$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, mp.mathematical-physics, sg.symplectic-geometry

We know this fact that the first jet Bundle $J^1M$ is diffeomorphic with $T^*M×\mathbb{R}$.i.e,
($J^1M=T^*M×\mathbb{R}$)

Is there something like this identity for higher jet bundle $J^kM$?

I editted my question after comment of Michael Murray

Comment: Your diffeomorphism is true when you take the jet bundle of the trivial line bundle $M \times \mathbb{R} \to M$, but false in general.

Comment: You can see this fact in Example 1.3. in part Cotangent bundles and 1-Jet Bundles. here http://www.math.ias.edu/files/wam/Traynorlecture.pdf

Comment: Second reference , see Example 6.7 of http://faculty.tcu.edu/richardson/Seminars/symplectic.pdf

Comment: Okay, it seems some mathematicians choose a definition that only covers this special case.  Thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: You don't need $M$ to be compact.  This is a local fact about the exterior derivative splitting the jet exact sequence.

Comment: Michael Murray, Yes, you right, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, note that there is a natural exact sequence of bundle maps
$$
Sym^kT^*M \rightarrow J^kM \rightarrow J^{k-1}M
$$
but there is no natural splitting of this sequence. You can, however, do it by choosing a Riemannian metric and defining a map $J^{k-1}M \rightarrow J^kM$ by extending a $(k-1)$-jet to the $k$-jet whose symmetrized $k$-th order covariant derivatives all vanish at the point. From this you can conclude that there exists a bundle isomorphism
$$
J^kM = \mathbb{R} \oplus T^*M \oplus Sym^2T^*M \oplus\cdots \oplus Sym^kT^*M.
$$
This is all explained in the algebraic geometric context in section 2.4 of [these notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/files/jets.pdf). My guess is that it is all explained in the book "The Geometry of Jet Bundles" by Saunders.

Comment: Dear Deane Yang@ what is the third part ,i.e,$B$ of your equality $$
J^kM = \mathbb{R} \oplus T^*M \oplus B\cdots \oplus Sym^kT^*M.
$$

Comment: It is $B=Sym^2T^*M$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Deane Yang@ Can you clarify you notation of $Sym^kT^*M$ ?

Comment: Symmetric $k$-tensors on $M$.