# Symplectic structure on $Sym^kG^{\mathbb{C}} $

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, mp.mathematical-physics, lie-algebras, sg.symplectic-geometry

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group, and let $G^\mathbb{C}$ be its [complexification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification_%28Lie_group%29).
I am looking for a symplectic structure (without use of coordinates) on 
$$
Sym^kG^{\mathbb{C}},
$$
PS:Here $G^{\mathbb{C}}=T^*G$.(this equality is trivial by polar decomposition in the case, when $G$ is compact Lie group )

i.e. on the space of all [symmetric tensors of order $k$ d](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_tensor)efined on $G^\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that such a thing exists? And I don't understand the notation; is this the $k^{th}$ symmetric power of the tangent bundle?

Comment: Dear  Qiaochu , I edited it.

Comment: It is not clear what you really want: the space $Sym^kG^{\Bbb C}$ is not smooth, and there are several different definitions of symplectic structures on singular spaces.

Comment: Misha Verbitsky, I didn't know this fact.I know that $$
Sym^kG^{\mathbb{C}}=Sym^kT^*G,
$$,do you have any referrence about  symplectic structures on singular spaces. ?

Comment: Misha Verbitsky, In fact for order 2, we have $Sym^2 G^\mathbb{C}=J^2G/(\mathbb{R}\oplus T^*G)$ this space is not Smooth?

Comment: @Misha: the notation is a little unclear; it does not refer to the symmetric power of the space but to the symmetric power of its cotangent bundle.

Comment: @Peter: I don't think this is right. The local picture is not $\text{Sym}^k(V)$ where $V$ is a symplectic vector space, it's $V \oplus \text{Sym}^k(V^{\ast})$ where $V$ is a vector space.

Comment: @Hassan: I still don't understand the motivation for this question, especially in light of the observations in my answer. What reason did you have for believing that such a thing existed?

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan, you are definitely correct.

Comment: The notation is very strange. Usually if $X$ is a variety, $\text{Sym}^k X$ means the quotient of the Cartesian product $\prod^k X$ by the symmetric group on $k$ letters.

Comment: It is easy to see by polar decomposition that the complexification of compact Lie Group, $G^{\mathbb{C}}$ is just $T^*G$, i.e,$G^{\mathbb{C}}=T^*G$. Also if $J^2G$ be the Jet bundle of Lie group $G$ of second order, then by decomposition of jet bundle of higher order, we can get$Sym^2 G^\mathbb{C}=J^2G/(\mathbb{R}\oplus T^*G)$. See  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/146636/looking-for-an-identity-for-higher-jet-bundle-jkm?rq=1

Comment: Also for $k=3$we have, $Sym^3 G^\mathbb{C}=J^3G/(\mathbb{R}\oplus G^\mathbb{C}\oplus J^2G/(\mathbb{R}\oplus G^\mathbb{C}))$ and ect...

Comment: @Hassan: I am still confused. Why did you bring in the complexification if you just wanted to talk about the cotangent bundle of $G$? And, again, why do you think there's a symplectic structure on jet bundles?

Comment: I am trying to solve a question about complexification of lie group. Thats why I always use of complexification :). But I guess, it is now clear. Also I will add this part in my question. Also I didn't said there's a symplectic structure on jet bundles here. I know that Jet bundle has contact structure . I guess for Jet bundles of higher order we need to multisymplectic structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a thing doesn't exist. The symmetric square of the cotangent bundle of a real $n$-dimensional manifold has dimension $n + {n+1 \choose 2}$, which is in particular odd whenever $n \equiv 2 \bmod 4$. So for example we can take $G = \text{SU}(2), G_{\mathbb{C}} = \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$, which has real dimension $6$.

Comment: If we take the bundle $B$ whose sections are the holomorphic symmetric 2-tensors on the complex manifold $X=G_{\mathbb{C}}$, then $X$ is Kaehler and so is $B$. Maybe that is what this is about?